# PHP MYSQLi query only accesses user on first row

Tags: php, mysqli

Follow the links above, in sequence, for an example of a username & password login web based system, developed using PHP, JavaScript and a MySQL database.
Follow the links above, in sequence, for an example of a username & password login web based system, developed using PHP, JavaScript and a MySQL database.

Follow the links above, in sequence, for an example of a username & password login web based system, developed using PHP, JavaScript and a MySQL database.

Comment: How are you checking passwords, out of interest? In particular, are you hashing them with `hash_password()`? Make sure you are not storing them in plain text.

Comment: @halfer: I am simply hashing it with md5. I plan to hash and look into salting later. Right now I'm just trying to get it to work (it still doesn't work trying the below approach).

Comment: OK, `MD5()` is effectively broken for password storage. If you are interested, my profile contains a tutorial that demonstrates how to do user login safely and correctly.

Comment: @halfer: I will look into it once I achieve this. Thank you

Comment: In relation to the problem here, "doesn't work" is generally regarded as a fault report that doesn't say very much. Have you defined the function `sanitize()`? - the poster should have made it clear this needs implementing. Do you have errors turned on in your dev environment?

Comment: Also, look up each of the functions you are using, `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_fetch_array`, and check they are being called correctly, and check their output. The query will fail if you are not connected to the database, for example. It is worth putting in a check to ensure the query worked before trying to obtain results from it.

Comment: It looks like you're using `$_POST['x']` to pass around the connection resource in a global state.  That is _really_ confusing and a strange abuse of `$_POST`. I would instead recommend using `$GLOBALS['conn'] = mysqli_connect(....)` and reference via `$GLOBALS['conn']`. That is what its intended for, after all, where `$_POST` has a very different purpose.   [info on `$GLOBALS`....](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowsi , I thought it had something to do with $_POST['x'], I also have two forms on one page, a login and signup... so you're probably right. I'll read into it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing only the first row of the table user. When you test using the if statement, the first row returned is either the user trying to log in, or not.

Instead, you can do the following:

```
function user_exists($username) {

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysqli_query($_POST['x'], "SELECT * FROM users where username ='".$username."'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    if(count($row)>0) {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;       
}
```

This looks for all rows with the given username. Of course, testing passwords or other things will depend on actually iterating through the array fetched, instead of just checking the count.

Comment: Not bad, but probably better to use parameterisation? You can get rid of the `sanitize()` function then too.

Comment: @Kazux I have edited it, please see the above but now neither records are being found. What else could possibly be wrong?

Comment: You're going to need to single quote `'$username'` in that query.

Comment: @halfer - apologies; I didn't see a popup. My edits still go to the queue for approval,  so I'm not sure the same workforce applies

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it yesterday thanks to you guys. It works well however is needed to be repeated in other functions involved (which is what failed) and yes I forgot my error reporting was turned off, making life harder for myself:

```
function user_exists($username) {

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysqli_query($_POST['x'], "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    if (count($rows) > 0) {
        return true;} else return false;
}
```

Same done for the login function:

```
function login($username, $password){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = mysqli_query($_POST['x'], "SELECT `userid` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    if(count($rows) > 0) {
        $userid = user_id_from_username($username);
        return $userid; }  else return false;
```

Thanks again!